# Angular auth-0 - How to NOT send "Bearer" token in certain requests

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, auth0

I'm trying to wrangle the auth-0 angular plugin for JWTs and I'm stuck in a spot where I've setup the jwtInterceptor to push a JWT token into the headers of every single request made.

Here is my code:

```
// Send JWT with every request
  jwtInterceptorProvider.tokenGetter = ['config', function(config) {
    var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ngStorage-user'));
    var token = user.token;
    return token;
  }];

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor');
```

The problem is that there are a few instances where I need to make a call where I DON'T send the token in the headers of the request, such as getting the initial JWT token on registration. As of right now, with my code, if there is no JWT set, it results in an error.

One of other thought I had was to just edit each call to send the token in the headers manually, however I can't seem to get the request to work with ngResource:

```
function getCourseCatalog(token) {
      return Registrar.checkToken($localStorage.user.token).then(function(data) {
               return $resource($rootScope.APIBaseURL + 'catalog',{
                  query: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: true,
                    headers: {
                      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.user.token
                    }
                  }
                });
             });
    }
```

^ With this function, the call never gets made and I'm pretty sure this is exactly how you're supposed to setup the $resource call. Is there something I'm missing? This particular call is hitting an endpoint that gets an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the function was missing a parameter, but additionally, I needed to still run the query() function on $resource in order to actually make the call. The new function looks like this:

```
function getCourseCatalog(token) {
      return Registrar.checkToken($localStorage.user.token).then(function(data) {
               return $resource($rootScope.APIBaseURL + 'catalog',{},{
                  query: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: true,
                    headers: {
                      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.user.token
                    }
                  }
                }).query();
             });
    }
```